# Parse CSV and export into Mysql database in Grails

Tags: mysql, grails

I am newbie in Groovy & Grails. I want to submit  parse CSV file and export into several tables of MySQL database.
I have looked some coding but it was confusing for me as newbie.
So can anybody help me in understanding simple csv file Parsing and exporting into MySQL database.

Thanks
Sonu

Answer (score 11):

Grails a bootstrap process that runs whenever your app starts. Its nifty; you can configure it to do different things in different environments.

One approach is to do the following in bootstrap:

1)  Read the csv file, creating Domain objects as you go.
2)  For each domain object, check to see if it exists, and if not do youDomainObject.save()

thats it.

for code, something like

```
new File(filePath).splitEachLine(',') {fields ->
    def domainObject = new YouDomainObject(
        id: fields[0].trim(),
        name: fields[1].trim()
    )

    if (domainObject.hasErrors() || domainObject.save(flush: true) == null) {
        log.error("Could not import domainObject  ${domainObject.errors}")
    }

    log.debug("Importing domainObject  ${domainObject.toString()}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Groovy integrates with Java you can also use a Java library called [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to read the CSV if you're more comfortable with that.