# How to import CSV file into Mysql using grails

Tags: mysql, grails, csv, twitter-bootstrap

I want to import CSV file into database. From database i have to read and display data in type ahead control of twitter bootstrap using grails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784226/parse-csv-and-export-into-mysql-database-in-grails). Also [this](http://compiledammit.com/2013/02/14/pwned-csv-exportimport-with-grails/) will help you, too.