# how to take data from csv file and save into grails with mysql?

Tags: mysql, grails, csv, groovy

example :
i have a CSV file like this

[image]

and i want it save in to database..with upload the CSV's files.

this is my coding for upload CSV file

```
<input type="file" name="filecsv"/>
<input type="button" class="upload" value="Upload 
             onclick='location.href ="${createLink(url: [action: 'upload'])}"'/>
```

i confuse in groovy..i tried like this code but not success.

```
    def upload = {
        println params.filecsv
    new File('filecsv').splitEachLine(',') {fields ->
    def city = new City(
        city: fields[0].trim(),
        description: fields[1].trim()
    )

    if (city.hasErrors() || city.save(flush: true) == null) {
        log.error("Could not import domainObject  ${city.errors}")
    }

    log.debug("Importing domainObject  ${city.toString()}")
}
```

[Parse CSV and export into Mysql database in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784226/parse-csv-and-export-into-mysql-database-in-grails)

how to get data from file CSV and save it into database mysql?

Comment: http://grails.org/plugin/excel-import might be worth a look

Comment: Also, what does _"...but not success"_ mean?  Did you get an error?

Comment: i already edit my post, i can't get this path "<input type="file" name="filecsv"/>" but it success if new File('C:\\user\\desktop\\book1.csv').splitEachLine(',') {fields ->

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to get the InputStream from the [MultipartFile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html) you are passed [as shown in the documentation:](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#uploadingFiles)

```
<g:uploadForm action="upload">
    <input type="file" name="filecsv" />
    <input type="submit" />
</g:uploadForm>
```

Then;

```
def upload = {
    request.getFile( 'filecsv' )
          .inputStream
          .splitEachLine(',') { fields ->
        def city = new City( city: fields[0].trim(),
                             description: fields[1].trim() )

        if (city.hasErrors() || city.save(flush: true) == null) {
            log.error("Could not import domainObject  ${city.errors}")
        }

        log.debug("Importing domainObject  ${city.toString()}")
    }
}
```

Comment: 2014-01-27 16:44:54,047 [http-8080-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - No signature of method: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [filecsv]
Possible solutions: getXML(), getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getLocale(), getJSON(), getHeader(java.lang.String)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.getFile()

Comment: You're using `uploadForm` in the GSP yeah?

Comment: only this in g:form <span class="button">
               
               <input type="file" name="filecsv"/>
               <input type="button" class="upload"
                                            value="Upload"
                                            onclick='location.href = "${createLink(url: [action: 'upload'])}"'/>
              
             </span>

Comment: I mean the top bit of my answer...  It needs to be in an upload form Or a multipart form

Answer (score 0):

You could do this way.

1. use the Grails CSV plugin to upload and parse the CSV files

> ```
> plugins {       
>       //TODO other plugins          
>       compile(":csv:0.3.1") // add this entry in BuildConfig.groovy        
>     }
> ```

make sure you have the csv data in controller/service and here you go

1. in controller/service use below logic

   ```
   //Read the CSV file data excluding the header    
   filecsv.inputStream.toCsvReader(['skipLines':1]).eachLine { tokens ->    
   //parse the csv columns
   def name= tokens[0].trim()
   def class= tokens[1].trim()
   def age = tokens[2].trim()
   def phone = tokens[3].trim()

   //assign the csv column values to domain object
   City city = new City() // this is your domain/table that you used to insert csv data   
   city.name = name
   city.class = class
   city.age = age
   if(!city.save(validate: true)){
     city.errors.each {
     log.debug(it)
     }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: The issue isn't currently the parsing of the CSV, it's the getting a multipart form in a controller