# Get the next row while importing file CSV in groovy

Tags: mysql, sql, grails, csv, groovy

i ever ask a question at this link

[how to take data from csv file and save into grails with mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375442/how-to-take-data-from-csv-file-and-save-into-grails-with-mysql/21377658#21377658)

i am confuse..how to read next row..so the file csv like this

row 1 : bobby,1,20,628129456774,**2** //this 2 means its have 2 child, it will import to different table.
row 2 : singer,50% 
row 3 : dance,50%

so first line it will insert to table **PERSON** and the last digit "**2**" means table **PERSON** have 2 **Child**..
the row 2 and 3 will insert to table **Hobby** where the domain like thiss.

```
package com.teravin.collection.maintenance

import java.util.Date;

class Hobby{
    String hobby
    String likess
    Person person
    static constraints = {

    }

    def beforeInsert = {
        //        createdBy = springSecurityService.principal.username
        createDate = new Date()
    }

    def beforeUpdate = {
        //        updatedBy = springSecurityService.principal.username
        lastUpdated = new Date()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample: It loops to read next line from csv

public List Sample()
        {

```
        List<wsSample> result = new List<wsSample>();

        string path = @"C:\Users\c_evtamondong\Desktop\sampleCsv.csv";

        StreamReader csvSample = new StreamReader(path);
        DataTable oDataTable = new DataTable();


        int rowCount = 0;
        string[] columnNames = null;
        string[] CsvValues = null;

        while (!csvSample.EndOfStream)
        {
            string RowData = csvSample.ReadLine().Trim();

            if (RowData.Length > 0)
            {
                CsvValues = RowData.Split(new string[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.None);

                if (rowCount == 0) //check if it's in the first line
                {
                    rowCount = 1;
                    columnNames = CsvValues;
                    foreach (string csvHeader in columnNames)
                    {
                        // do nothing
                        // to eliminate the header in the .csv file
                    }


                }
                else
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < CsvValues.Length-1; i++ )
                    {

                            result.Add(new wsSample()
                            {
                                id = CsvValues[i],
                                name = CsvValues[i + 1],
                                lastname = CsvValues[i + 2]
                            });
                            i = i + 1;


                    }


                }
            }
        }

        csvSample.Close();
        csvSample.Dispose();


            return result;
        }
```

Comment: are there have another way to use with "Trim"? because i already use "Trim"

Comment: this is how to use trim
string str = Something.Trim();

Comment: or in java

import java.io.*;

public class Test{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      String Str = new String("   Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com   ");

      System.out.print("Return Value :" );
      System.out.println(Str.trim() );
   }
}